# MessageHeader.CreateHeader is adding xmlns="" to all attributes in serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf, .net-core

Im trying to call an old WCF .NET service from a new .NET Core 3.1 project. I want to add a custom header to the SOAP request, so I created a IClientMessageInspector and on BeforeSendRequest I am creating and adding my header like so :
`var header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("StartRequest", "http://mynamespace", headerValue); request.Headers.Add(header);`

The header value is based on an instance of a regular c# class with attribute `[DataContract(Namespace = "")]`

All properties of the class are decorated with `[DataMember]`

My issue is, when I look at the request in fiddler I see that all the properties received xmlns="" when serialized. This breaks SOAP contract and my request fails. I tried to use a DataContractSerializer but couldnt figure out how to prevent if from generating xmlns.

Has anyone else solved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by making header class inherit MessageHeader and overwriting OnWriteHeaderContents.